# php dropdown menu with deafult selected value

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, default-value

I am working on a PHP project as follows

```
 if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
    echo '<select name="officerlist">';
    while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {                       
       echo '<option>' . $rows['officer'] . '</option>';
       if ($types[ $maxindex ] == $rows['officer']){
        echo ' selected';
       }
    }
        echo '</select>';
}
```

I am able to populate the query result into the dropdown menu. However, I want to implement it to have a default selected value based on value from another array. (ie if $types[$maxindex] is found in $rows['officer'], it will auto select the value.).

Anyone able to advise?

Thank you and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be like this,

```
while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array ($result) ) {                       

    if ($types[$maxindex] == $rows['officer']){
        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$rows['officer'].'">' . $rows['officer'] . '</option>';
    } else {
       echo '<option value="'.$rows['officer'].'">' . $rows['officer'] . '</option>';
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hi jogesh_pi, thank you for the prompt response. Did compiled the suggested codes but value is still not displaying as default.

Comment: @user3237459 what is this `$maxindex`? it simply means the condition not match in `if ($types[$maxindex] == $rows['officer']){` part, Try to debug it to echo the `$types[$maxindex]` and check what value your are matching with.

Comment: hello. yes it is matching. did an echo to verify its content. It is one of the matching selection found in $rows['officer'].

Comment: @user3237459 take a look on html source code or use firebug / developer's toolkit and verify that you get the value like `<option selected="selected">` or not.

Comment: hi, retrieved from page source : <option  selected="selected" >Mr John</option>. It is the value matching $types[$maxindex]. However, it is not shown as default highlighted when displaying the page.

Comment: @user3237459 i think this is because of all the option values are blank, let i update the code; and try like it. hope this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if( mysql_num_rows($result)>0 ) {
echo '<select name="officerlist">';
while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array ($result) ) {                       
if ($types[$maxindex] == $rows['officer']){
    echo '<option selected="selected">' . $rows['officer'] . '</option>';    
}
else
{
    echo '<option>' . $rows['officer'] . '</option>';

}
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add the `selected` attribute inside the `<option>` tag, like

`<option selected='selected'>youroption</option>`.

Try this,

```
if( mysql_num_rows($result)>0 ) {
    echo '<select name="officerlist">';
    while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array ($result) ) {
        $selected ="";
        if ($types[$maxindex] == $rows['officer']){
            $selected = ' selected="selected" ';
        }
        echo '<option '.$selected.'>' . $rows['officer'] . '</option>';

    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array ($result) ) {                       

    if ($types[$maxindex] == $rows['officer']){
        echo '<option SELECTED>' . $rows['officer'] . '</option>';
    } else {
       echo '<option>' . $rows['officer'] . '</option>';
    }
   }
```